# Jquery - Store element text in variable for access after it has been altered

Tags: jquery

Any help would be appreciated on this one, I'm a newbie when it comes to jquery and javascript but I have this section of code which I hashed together:

```
$('.comment-data').click(function() {
    var ThisData = $(this);
    var Thistitle = ThisData.find('h4');
    var original = Thistitle.text();
    var ThisNext = ThisData.next().find('ol');
    ThisNext.stop(true, true).customToggle(500, function() {
    ThisNext.is(':visible') ? Thistitle.text('Hide Comments') : Thistitle.text(original);
});
});
```

it works fine apart from one thing; I need to store the initial text stored in the 'original' variable and keep that the same to access after I make a change to the text (replacing with 'Hide Comments'). Hope this makes sense, at the moment I assume variable Thistitle is being changed to value 'Hide Comments' then I am in effect writing over the original variable with this, hence when I set the text to my original variable I get 'Hide Comments'.

Thanks in advance for any insight into how to fix this, I have tried using .data but this just hashed everything up!

Comment: or you can just use data attributes to store the original text.. like `data-original="youroriginaltext"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the variable declaration to outside the click event..

```
var original = "";

$('.comment-data').click(function() {
    // Your code here
    if( original === ''){
        original = Thistitle.text();
        // Only set if the variable is empty
    }
    // Then use the initial value here
}
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks wirey for your solution, it nearly worked but I can only get the original text data from some php which returns  full html, it got messy very quick. I had tried declaring the variable outside the click function like so: var original; but it didn't work, this did tho @Sushanth thank you very much :-)

Comment: @OliverFoxley .. you are welcome.. But if data-attributes method work then it is better to follow that as Wirey proposed as that would be a cleaner approach .. :)

Comment: EDIT ---

Ah I thought it was working, unfortunately this seems to return the same original text value for all individual elements, I need it to remember the text for each individual element.

Basically I have this php:

<?php comments_number('<h4>No Comments</h4>', '<h4>Show Comments (1)</h4>', '<h4>Show Comments (%)</h4>'); ?>

which returns my text wrapped in an h4 tag. I need to save this text for later and toggle between 'Hide Comments' and whatever was present as the text to start with, e.g 'Show Comments (4)', this gets the same text for all the elements this applies to on the page.